# Listing word final consonants cluster in German

Tags: python, regex, cluster-computing, final

I wrote a program that finds and counts initial consonant clusters in German and Spanish texts. I want a regex that will find clusters on final positions. Using \b or $ does not work. Can someone help me determine how I should change my regex so that it will work for final consonants clusters?

I currently have sth like this for initial clusters:

```
for w in words:
    initial = re.search('^([^aeiouy]*)[aeiouy]',w)
```

Or sth like this:

```
 initial = re.search('^[^aeiouy]{2,}',w)
```

Comment: Try `re.search(r'[^aeiouy]{2,}\b', w)` or `re.search(r'[^aeiouy]+$', w)`

Comment: Actually, already tried that and the outcome of using it is just a list of words with frequency. I am looking for sth like in English 'singing' - the outcome should be: 'ng' cluster. So now that I am thinking maybe it should be a code more like this: `(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){2,}` but with modification to final cluster, still doesn't work

Comment: Try `(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){2,}$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZcHT1/1).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to extract chunks of 2 or more consonant letters at the end of the string.

You may use

```
(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){2,}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZcHT1/2).

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?![aeiou])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next char is a vowel
  - `[a-z]` - an ASCII letter (case insensitive mode can be set with `re.I` flag)
- `){2,}` - end of the group, 2 or more occurrences
- `$` - end of string.